# My PHP Contact Form is not working

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I am creating a website and I was making a contact form with PHP.  It is turning up no errors on the page itself but the email never shows up in the inbox or spam folder of my email.  The code I have for it is:

```
        $_NAME = $_POST["name"];
        $_EMAIL = $_POST["reply"];
        $_SUBJECT = $_POST["subject"];
        $_MESSAGE = $_POST["message"];

        $_MAILTO = "myemail@gmail.com";
        $_SUBJECT = "Contact Form";
        $_FORMCONTENT = "From: ".$_NAME." Subject: ".$_SUBJECT." Message: ".$_MESSAGE;
        $_MAILHEADER = "Reply To: ".$_EMAIL;

        mail($_MAILTO, $_SUBJECT, $_FORMCONTENT, $_MAILHEADER);
```

Any ideas what the problem is?

EDIT --

Here's the HTML form:

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="contact2.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name (optional)" onfocus="placeholder=''" onblur="placeholder='Your name (optional)'" /><br><br>
                <input type="text" class="reply" id="reply" name="reply" placeholder="Your email (optional)" onfocus="placeholder=''" onblur="placeholder='Your email (optional)'" /><br><br>
                <input type="text" class="subject" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" onfocus="placeholder=''" onblur="placeholder='Subject'" /><br><br>
                <textarea class="message" id="message" name="message" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your message" onfocus="placeholder=''" onblur="placeholder='Enter your message'"></textarea><br><br>
                <input type="submit" class="send" id="send" name="send" value="Send Message" />
            </form>
```

Comment: Please provide your complete code including the HTML form.

Comment: Are you testing on localhost? If so move the script to a hosted server and try it there. Variables names in all capital letters aren't very nice too look at. Make sure to validate and sanitize user's input as well.

Comment: Is your SMTP server properly configured in php.ini ? Is your SMTP server working ? If you have access to your SMTP server logs, do you see any errors/messages ?

Comment: Although it's not wrong *per se*, I must tell you that the style you chose for naming your variables is not very smart. You **can** use `$name` instead of `$_NAME`, or `$email` instead of `$_EMAIL`, as variables that have underscore at the beginning are typically used by PHP for (at least) superglobal variables (like **$_POST** or **$_GET**) and doing that in others can lead to confusion. More info on superglobals here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to check the return value of the mail function to see if the email was successfully (as far as PHP/mail function can ascertain) sent.

```
$mail_result = mail($_MAILTO, $_SUBJECT, $_FORMCONTENT, $_MAILHEADER);
if ($mail_result) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div>Mail was successfully sent!</div>
HTML;
} else {
    echo <<<HTML
<div>Sending mail failed!</div>
HTML;
}
```

Secondly, you should check that all appropriate settings are correctly set in your php.ini file, specifically the sendmail_path setting. You should definitely take a look at **[official documentation in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)**.

As a last ditch effort, you may want to look into an **[alternate](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail)** method of sending the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example:

```
<?php

// Has the form been submitted?
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    // Set some variables
    $required_fields = array('name', 'email'); // add fields as needed
    $errors = array();

    $success_message = "Congrats! Your message has been sent successfully!";
    $sendmail_error_message = "Oops! Something has gone wrong, please try later.";

    // Cool the form has been submitted! Let's loop 
    // through the required fields and check
    // if they meet our condition(s)
    foreach ($required_fields as $fieldName) {
        // If the current field in the loop is NOT part of the form submission -OR-
        // if the current field in the loop is empty
        if (!isset($_POST[$fieldName]) || empty($_POST[$fieldName])) {

            // add a reference to the errors array, indicating that these conditions have failed
            $errors[$fieldName] = "The {$fieldName} is required!";
        }
    }

    // Proceed if there aren't any errors
    if (empty($errors)) {
        // add fields as needed
        $name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
        $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );

        // Email receivers
        $to_emails = "anonymous1@example.com, anonymous2@example.com";

        $subject = 'Contact form sent from ' . $name;
        $message = "From: {$name}";
        $message .= "Email: {$email}";

        $headers = "From: {$name}\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: {$email}\r\n";
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        if (mail($to_emails, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            echo $success_message;
        } else {
            echo $sendmail_error_message;
        }
    } else {

        foreach($errors as $invalid_field_msg) {
            echo "<p>{$invalid_field_msg}</p>";
        }
    }
}
```